# Rasa chatbot can't access weather-apixu API

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa-core, rasa

I have been stuck with a problem with my Weather bot. The conversation works fine except for the action of doing the weather forecast after specifying the location, which is the main action actually. I am using the Apixu for the weather forecast

When I run the online training I get this error:

```
ERROR:rasa_core.processor:Encountered an exception while running action 'action_weather'. Bot will continue, but the actions events are lost. Make sure to fix the exception in your custom code.
```

This is my python script for the action of weather forecast:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import from __future__ import division
__future__ import unicode_literals


from rasa_core.actions.action import Action from rasa_core.events
import SlotSet from apixu.client import ApixuClient

class ActionWeather(Action):
     def name(self):
         return 'action_weather'

     def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

         api_key = '6******************'
         client = ApixuClient(api_key)

         loc = tracker.get_slot('location')
         current = client.getCurrentWeather(q=loc)

         country = current['location']['country']
         city = current['location']['name']
         condition = current['current']['condition']['text']
         temperature_c = current['current']['temp_c']
         humidity = current['current']['humidity']
         wind_mph = current['current']['wind_mph']

         response = """It is currently {} in {} at the moment. The temperature is {} degrees, the humidity is {}%
          and the wind speed is {} mph.""".format(condition, city, temperature_c, humidity, wind_mph)

         dispatcher.utter_message(response)
         return [SlotSet('location', loc)]
```

and this is my weather domain file which is a yaml file

```
 slots:   location:
     type: text


 intents:
  - greet
  - goodbye
  - inform


 entities:
  - location

 templates:   utter_greet:
     - 'Hello! How can I help?'   utter_goodbye:
     - 'Talk to you later.'
     - 'Bye bye :('   utter_ask_location:
     - 'In what location?'



 actions:
  - utter_greet
  - utter_goodbye
  - utter_ask_location
  - actions.ActionWeather
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Here is an update of the error :
ERROR:rasa_core.processor:Error code 1003: "Parameter q is missing."

Answer (score 0):

As your bot is in Python, the program is either using ruamel.yaml or PyYAML to parse the YAML file.

If you try to parse your YAML file, it is clear that it is invalid on the first line:

```
import ruamel.yaml
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

yaml_str = """\
 slots:   location:
     type: text
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
```

gives:

```
ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 19:
     slots:   location:
                      ^ (line: 1)
```

You can also try this [online](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/).

Your bot is most likely catching these errors but not taking proper action upon them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The problem was with the API . I changed it and now it works